# Load SSIS multiple files one by one

Tags: ssis, foreach-loop-container

I'm using the `foreach` loop container in my SSIS job and I have a folder where we add new files every day containing the name + date.

I need to run the package using the oldest file; after that we load the second one.

Can we change this bulk insert in SSIS jobs?

FI: I used variables to load them (FolderPath and folderName) but they are processed at the same time; I prefer another solution than using script.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is confusing, but I'll try to answer.
If you don't want to use the script component I will suggest...
1.Using a foreach loop container (folder as source) read the file names into a two column table (Filename (full path), datepart from file name)
2.Using another foreach loop container (using ado object as source) select from that table in the desired order to fill ado object.
Load files that match the path